# Angular2 - firebase returning denormalized query

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am trying to write a query for a denormalized database, using the example from [Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html), what I am trying to do is:

get the list of forms under the current user
for each item in this list return a reference to each item

Here is my code:

```
  getFormList():firebase.database.Reference {
    // the old method
    //return firebase.database().ref('/formsByID').orderByChild('userList').startAt(this.userId).endAt(this.userId);

    var formRef = firebase.database().ref("/formsByID");
    var userRef = firebase.database().ref("/userProfiles");

    // this is our list of forms under the child node
    var userFormRef = userRef.child(this.userId).child("formsList");

    // when an item is added to our list of forms
    userFormRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {
      // snap.key is key of our form taken from forms list
      //let formKey = snap.key(): string;
      return formRef.child(snap.key);
    }); 

  }
```

The problem is that typescript is expecting a value to return from my getFormList method, but a value will only return when a new value is added to my userFormRef - any help appreciated

Comment: Perhaps I need to split this into 2 functions - will try that

Answer (score 0):

The `getFormList()` method will never return a value in your case.

You're `return` statement belongs to the callback function.

```
userFormRef.on("child_added", function(snap) {
  return formRef.child(snap.key); // this returns a value for your callback function
});
```

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to get access to the `snap` outside of the `getFormList()` method you would need to implement it there or pass the callback to the `getFormList()` method.

This would look like this:

```
 getFormList(cb):firebase.database.Reference {
    // the old method
    //return firebase.database().ref('/formsByID').orderByChild('userList').startAt(this.userId).endAt(this.userId);

    var formRef = firebase.database().ref("/formsByID");
    var userRef = firebase.database().ref("/userProfiles");

    // this is our list of forms under the child node
    var userFormRef = userRef.child(this.userId).child("formsList");

    // when an item is added to our list of forms
    userFormRef.on("child_added", cb); 
  }
```

And the method call would look like this:

```
getFormList(function(snap) {
  // do something with your snap outside the function
});
```

But yeah it hardly depends on your use case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - I ended up figuring the answer out thanks to what you told me - will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out with thanks to @Orlandster. The issue was that I was trying to do to much in my providers. When working with angular and firebase really your providers should only return a reference. I rewrote my providers into 2 methods like this:

```
  // this returns a list of forms (ref) of the current user
  getUserFormsRef(): firebase.database.Reference {
    var userRef = firebase.database().ref("/userProfiles");
    return userRef.child(this.userId).child("formsList");
  }

  // this returns a form list (ref)
  getFormListRef(): firebase.database.Reference {
    return firebase.database().ref("/formsByID");
  }
```

Then on my component itself I do the following:

```
  // list the forms
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    // get a list of the users forms as a reference
    this.formProvider.getUserFormsRef().on("child_added", userFormsSn => {
      this.formList = [];
      // get the forms reference based on the keys returned from our users forms reference
      // then push into our form list array - voila!
      this.formProvider.getFormListRef().child(userFormsSn.key).on("value", formsSn => {
        this.formList.push({
          id: formsSn.key,
          name: formsSn.val().name
        })
      });
    });
  }
```

Once again the trick is that calls to my formProvider only ever return a database reference object type. This is essentially how you can do a Firebase equivalent of a WHERE query in a denormalized data set.